# Next iteration in z-order curve

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, quadtree, octree

I am building a quadtree using the techniques described in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).
I am storing the coordinates in an 2- or 3-dimansional array.

```
boost::array<unsigned int, 2 /* 3 */> coord;
```

I need a method to calculate the coordinates of the next box in z-order.
It would work by interleaving the bits, increasing by one and than deinterleaving, but this gets very complicated.
I hope there is an implementation similar to the cmp_zorder(...) methon in the article wich works without interleaving the bits.

Comment: What exactly do you want? The (x', y') that is next to (x, y) in Z-order, but without interleaving and de-interleaving?

Comment: Exactly right, is it possible?

Comment: Certainly, but I haven't heard (and can't find) any tricks, so the only way I can think of is modifying the bitwise addition algorithm to add the carries to the other coordinate (carries in x should be added to y, and carries in y should be added to x). A similar technique could be used for the 3D Z-curve. That doesn't sound particularly fast to me though. Are you interested in that way anyway?

Comment: yes, i'm intrested, sounds like a lot of bit operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the "mutilated" addition algorithm, `x` and `y` are inputs as well as outputs, and it is assumed that the lowest order bit in the interleaved coordinate would be `x` (the same as in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve))

```
int carry = 1;
do
{
    int newcarry = x & carry;
    x ^= carry;
    carry = newcarry;
    newcarry = (y & carry) << 1;
    y ^= carry;
    carry = newcarry;
} while (carry != 0);
```

I did test it, but only a little.